# como poner un Input de 2 variables de html jsp

Tags: java, jsp

No se si puedan ayudarme con esto, miren, les voy a mostrar códigos servlets, jsp y java:

Este es un método de una clase de consulta, y si, como lo vieron es para autenticar

```
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try { 
        String consulta = "SELECT * FROM rhcontino WHERE usuario = ? AND passw = ? AND empresa = ?";
        
        pst = getConexion().prepareStatement(consulta, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        pst.setString(1, usuario);
        pst.setString(2, contraseña);
        pst.setString(3, empresa);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.absolute(1)) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (getConexion() != null) {
                getConexion().close();
            }
            if (pst != null) {
                pst.close();
            }
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Este es del servlet que lo conecta, y si, que autentica, ahí van a ver una variable que al igual que en la input de jsp que verán mas adelante no está contemplada pero la puse para llamarlo como parámetro a la hora de autenticar, se trata de la variable nombre.

```
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
    String empresa = request.getParameter("empresa");
    String contraseña = request.getParameter("passw");
    
    Consultas c = new Consultas();
    
    if(c.Autenticacion(usuario, contraseña, empresa)){
        HttpSession sesion = request.getSession(true);
        sesion.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
        sesion.setAttribute("empresa", empresa);
        sesion.setAttribute("nombre", nombre);
        System.out.println(nombre + " Hola");

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("FotoContino.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
    else {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("errores.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

La codificación de la jsp se basa en Usuario con input de type text y name de usuario, Contraseña con input de type text de password, de name passw y Empresa de input de type text y con name empresa de acuerdo con las variables:

```html
<form action="Iniciar" method="post">
  <h4>Usuario: <input type="text" name="usuario" /></h4> 
  <h4>Contraseña: <input type="password" name="passw" /></h4> 
  <h4>Empresa: <input type="text" name="empresa" /></h4>
  <div align="center" >
    <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Primero lo que quería era que me devolviera el atributo nombre desde el usuario pero siempre me aparece nulo null desde que siempre lo imprimo e intente que autenticara tanto con el usuario como con el nombre, ambos con la contraseña como en facebook, lamentablemente no he encontrado el modo y pues no se que mas hacer, espero puedan ayudarme, saludos

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el formulario HTML como parte de la pregunta?

Comment: no me dejó la página, me marcaba error cuando lo intenté poner así, mas o menos va así <form action="Iniciar" method="post">
                <h4>Usuario: <input type="text" name="usuario" /></h4>
                <h4>Contraseña: <input type="password" name="passw" /></h4>
                <h4>Empresa: <input type="text" name="empresa" /></h4><div align="center" ><input type="submit" value="Ingresar" /></div></form>

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre cuando haces un submit de ese form? ¿Se muestra la págima FotoContinuo o la de errores?

Comment: Si me sale la página pero el usuario si sale, lo que me deja en null es al momento de querer requestear el dato del nombre de la persona, el carácter nombre